# How to get files back from Found folder in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista

A friend of mine lost all of her pictures, when she connected her camera to the pc, that runs Vista. It said, that the files are now in the `Found` folder. Could anyone point to a solution how to get those pics back, or where the folder is located?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disk check (chkdsk) Found folders (usually similar to "FOUND.000", "FOUND.001", etc.) are created in the root of the drive the files were recovered from:

[image: Found folder Example]

These folders are hidden, and by default Windows won't show you hidden files/folders.

Bleeping Computers has a nice tutorial on how to turn on viewing hidden files in Windows Vista [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial130.html), if you don't know how to turn them on already. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found is a folder that use used when the files system can no longer tell where they should rightfully be due to corruption. I would open that Found folder and copy them to another location.

After that, if that folder is on her computer, I would open a command bod and run this command: chkdsk /f and answer yes to doing it on reboot. Reboot the computer. I would do this at least twice.

If the Found folder is on the camera's memory, I would copy all the files off, and then format the removable memory card.

This is a cautionary tale to ALWAYS copy your pictures off the camera and eventually to a DVD or other secure place.

Comment: The problem is - there is no way of knowing where the `Found` folder is!

Comment: Ahh, usually right in the root...open My computer, go to the C drive, and look for a folder named Found. If on the memory card, go to that one, and look for Found. You may need to go up to the root directory.